# T-SQL One column in multiple columns select query

Tags: t-sql, split

I have a simple problem that I have not been able to find a solution to and I'm hoping someone on StackOverflow can help.

I currently have an example query as shown below

```
SELECT ID
     , ColumnName
  FROM Table
```

If I run this query I get the following result:

```
==================
ID | ColumnName
------------------
 1 | One_Two_Three
 2 | Four_Five_Six
==================
```

The result I'm after is as follows:

```
========================
ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3    
------------------------
 1 | One  | Two  | Three
 2 | Four | Five | Six
========================
```

Your assistence is appreciated.

Comment: this []http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql   Should help

Comment: Thanks for the link, the example does work using PARSENAME.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    ([ID] int, [ColumnName] varchar(13))


INSERT INTO @Table1
    ([ID], [ColumnName])
VALUES
    (1, 'One_Two_Three'),
    (2, 'Four_Five_Six')


;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  *,
                CAST('<d>' + REPLACE([ColumnName], '_', '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML) ColumnValue
        FROM    @Table1
)
SELECT  v.*,
        A.B.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
FROM    Vals v CROSS APPLY
        ColumnValue.nodes('/d') A(B)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb689/1)